# Wort für den Zeitraum, in dem man waschen kann

Tags: single-word-request, noun

Jede Woche gibt es sechs Stunden, in denen ich die Waschmaschinen benutzen darf. Wie kann man mit einem Wort diesen Zeitraum bezeichnen?

Zum Beispiel:

> Leider kann ich nicht ins Kino gehen. Heute ist mein(e) ***_*__*_*__** .
>
> Wie wäre es mit einem/r ***_*__*_*_** nächste Woche?

Comment: Bitte einen Satz :) (Das sollte vielleicht ins FAQ.)

Comment: @thei: Ok, ich habe jetzt zwei Versuche.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Es gibt das Wort **Waschtag**. Es ist zwar in Deinem Fall etwas ungenau, weil Du genau genommen nur sechs Stunden hast, es könnte aber ausreichen.

Dein Beispiel:

> Leider kann ich nicht ins Kino gehen, ich habe heute meinen Waschtag.

Alternativ kann man auch sowas sagen wie:

> Ich bin heute mit der Wäsche dran.

Answer (score 4):

Mir fällt  **Waschzeit** analog zu **Essenszeit** ein.

Ich wollte gerade in einem Kommentar bedauern, dass man keine ad hoc gebildeten Worte vorschlagen sollte.

Eine kurze Google Suche zeigt jedoch, dass dies Wort durchaus auch in dem von dir gefragten Sinne schon benutzt wird.

Häufiger meint man damit allerdings die Zeit, die eine Waschmaschine für den einzelnen Waschgang braucht.

Comment: Ehrlich gesagt würde ich schon sehr komisch gucken, wenn mir jemand sagt, dass heute seine Waschzeit ist.

Comment: Bei gemeinschaftlich genutzten Waschmaschinen _jetzt ist meine Waschzeit und nicht Ihre_ wäre ich kaum irritiert.

Comment: Ja, es hängt sehr vom Kontext ab. Ich habe in meinem Kommentar an das Beispiel aus der Frage gedacht: "Leider kann ich nicht ins Kino gehen. Heute ist meine Waschzeit." EDIT: Ich sehe gerade, dass ich bei dem Beispielsatz von splattne vielleicht _nicht_ komisch gucken würde, da der Begriff dort im Satz ein wenig erklärt wird.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt Da stimme ich dir völlig zu.

Answer (score 4):

Ich habe gerade mein 15minütiges Zeitfenster, um zu antworten, und schlage vor:

```
Ich habe heute ein Zeitfenster von 6 Stunden, um zu waschen.
```

Eventuell wäre ich sogar so mutig ein 'Waschfenster' selbständig zu etablieren. "Heute öffnet sich kurz mein Waschfenster, da kann ich nicht ins Kino!".

Auch aus der IT stammt die Zeitscheibe. Wir zerstückeln die Zeit wie die Wurst, und haben "eine 6stündige Zeitscheibe, in der wir waschen können."

Ich gebe aber zu, dass alle drei Formen etwas abseitig sind und eventuell Stirnrunzeln hevorrufen.

Answer (score 3):

Ich würde auch das Wort *"Waschtag"* verwenden. Wenn du präzise sein möchtest, könntest du es auch umschreiben mit:

> Ich kann heute nicht ins Kino, da ich meine zugeordnete (oder zugeteilte) Waschzeit nutzen muss.

Answer (score 3):

Ich würde mich nicht für *ein* Wort entscheiden, sondern es so umschreiben, wie Du es bereits getan hast:

> Ich kann heute leider nicht ins Kino gehen. Jede Woche gibt es sechs Stunden, in denen ich die Waschmaschinen benutzen darf, und die sind heute.

Den Vorschlag "Zeitfenster" finde ich aber auch gut.

Answer (score 2):

Die Einteilung kannst du "Waschküchenplan" nennen (das kommt aber auch darauf an, von welchen Waschmaschinen du sprichst).

Dein persönliches Zeitfenster im Waschküchenplan kann aber meiner Meinung nach nicht mit einem einzelnen Wort bezeichnet werden.

Vergleiche: http://www.juraforum.de/forum/aktuelle-juristische-diskussionen-und-themen/einseitige-aufstellung-waschkuechenplan-329263 für die Benutzung des Worts.

> Leider kann ich nicht ins Kino gehen. Heute ist mein (zugewiesener) Waschtag.
>
> Könnte ich die Waschküche nächste Woche benützen?